# Combinations of letters

Tags: combinatorics

I have been struggling the last hour on the following statement to workout out which method to use and and why that method gets used. Please keep the term simple because I am not a math genius.

> **Question.**
>
> How many different 5-letter sequences are there consisting of A's, B's, C's and D's are there in which the symbols in the first and fourth places are the same?

Am I correct in saying as there are 5 positions and the first and the last position are the same I say 3 positions $n=3$ and 4 choices $c = 4$ and the say $c^n$.

This will give 64 then multiply that by 4 because of the first and last positions being the same and get 256 as answer.

Comment: Consider each letter in our sequence separately. For our first letter, we have 4 possibilities. In the second, we have 4; in the third, similarly, we have 4. Now, the fourth, however, is required to be identical to our first, so we have only one possibility (i.e. the same one we picked for our first letter). Our fifth letter is similar to our second and third with 4 possibilities. The total number of possible sequences, then, is just $4\times4\times4\times1\times4=4^4=256$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: This is equivalent to how many 4 letter sequences there are with those letters.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Suppose that the first and fourth symbols are both A. Then you have $3$ slots to fill arbitrarily. In how many ways can you fill them? That’s the number of sequences that have A in the first and fourth slots. There are just as many with B in the first and fourth slots, and just as many again with C there, and ...